# Use JQuery to refresh table row using data after data updates in iframe

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, refresh

I have a simple table with a link that inserts a div (using JQuery) after the current TR, creates an Iframe and sets the contents of the IFrame to a page with a form relating to the table row I've selected.

After the form updates, it reloads the same page which triggers JQuery to update some content in the parent TR row, disabling some links and updating some data in TD cells to reflect changes made in the form.

This process means I have to code each element that needs updating, which means more things that can break.....

What I'd like to do is update the entire TR, which has a unique ID, by using the jQuery LOAD command.  I would call the same page as the one being displayed by the record's ID in the database - then I need to take the resulting TR on that LOADing page and insert it in place of the TR on the main page.

If I was using DIVs for the rows in the displayed data instead of tables, I'd do something like $('#myRowID').load('SameDatapage.asp?id=SameRecordid #divWithUniqueID')

so my question is - what code would I use to reload/replace just the affected TR by replacing its HTML(), if so, I don't know how to get just the HTML() from the page containing the TR which I would call in the LOAD command (which I don't think supports loading page parts with anything other than DIV  )

- OR -

is it legal to format a table like this:

```
<table>
<div id="1">
<tr>
  <td>some data</td>
</tr>
</div>
<div id="2">
<tr>
  <td>another row</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

to load the row inside the div or is that bad HTML?

Answer (score 0):

(not sure if I follow but)

You can just use the id's on your TR's:

```
<tr id="1">

code (something like this?):

var replacementRow = ;//your server request and data here

$('#1').html(replacementRow);
```

Comment: what i'm trying to do is sort of call the page recursively - I update the underlying data records and then I call the same page, wanting to extract the single row from the same table and replace it into the document.

Usually I do this with the load() function, though I don't think I can do this on a TR row and I don't want to hand build the <td></td> columns of the row and feed that to the line replacementRow=  

I am already using HTML() function from the child iframe to push updated data up to the parent TR row which has an ID for the row and <TD> that I want to update.